# Authentication for Fantasy Premier League API - Through XCode/Alamofire

Tags: swift, authentication, http-headers, token, alamofire-request

I am trying to use the Fantasy Premier League Api's, however for many of them I require a session token.

According to docs, in order to achieve this I need to create a POST request and send my password/login/redirect_uri. If successful I should receive my desired session token in the response headers (which I will later use in the requests needed).

[Example of how the request should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9efQ.png)

However one thing I have noticed is that the documentation contains examples using python, and I am not sure if I can achieve the same result using the XCode environment. I have no knowledge of Python and would love to know if I can achieve the authentication using only Alamofire/URLSession.

For additional info regarding this type of authentication, you can check out these posts.
**Guide 1:**
https://medium.com/@bram.vanherle1/fantasy-premier-league-api-authentication-guide-2f7aeb2382e4

**Guide 2:**
https://medium.com/@frenzelts/fantasy-premier-league-api-endpoints-a-detailed-guide-acbd5598eb19